# Moving steps in KMP algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

[KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is for searching and matching string with a given pattern. The most important part is to build a table for the pattern then move a proper step rather than just one step increment.

In my code I created the table correctly but something is wrong for moving steps.
It stuck in the for loop as variable was always equal to 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KMP
{
    class Program
    {
        const string pattern = "abcdabd";
        const string s = "aadabcdabedxdfabcdabddsa";
        static int[] x = new int[7];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            x = BuildTable(pattern);
            var y = Match(x, s);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static int Match(int[] x, string s)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int l = x.Length;
            int find = 0;
            Char[] charPattern = pattern.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; )
            {
                string a = s.Substring(i, l);
                if (a.CompareTo(pattern).Equals(0))
                {
                    return i; // Found match, return match position of the first letter
                }
                // move position by BuildTable
                Char[] charSubstring = a.ToCharArray();
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
                {
                    if (charPattern[j] == charSubstring[j])
                    {
                        count++;// count of matched chars
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i += count - x[j]; // move forward steps = matched count - table value
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return -999; // not found
        }

        public static int[] BuildTable(string p)
        {
            int[] result = new int[p.Length];
            result[0] = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < p.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                // The substring from p[1] to p[i]
                string s = p.Substring(0, i + 1);

                var prefixes = Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length - 1)
                     .Select(a => s.Substring(0, a)).ToList();
                var suffixes = Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length - 1)
                     .Select(a => s.Substring(a, s.Length - a)).ToList();
                var common = prefixes.Intersect(suffixes).FirstOrDefault();
                result[i] = (common == null) ? 0 : common.Length;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `if (charPattern[j] == charSubstring[j])` is true, you never advance the `i`..... and loop infinitely. Closing off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to read your code, since you use single letter variables (`x`, `s`, `l`... etc.).

Some more general concerns: `x` is a class member, initialized in its declaration, overriden in the `Main` method (without the initial value ever being used), and then passed as an argument to the `Match` method.

As for why the value is stuck on 2, my guess is that the line `i += count - x[j];` leaves the `i` value the same - `count - x[j] == 0` perhaps you meant to write `count + x[j]`?

Comment: What is the correct writing of a variable in C#? CamelCase?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1618325/1120015